# Use an environment variable set by PHP for specific Apache logs

Tags: php, apache

My goal is to write to different log files depending on **the execution of the PHP resource** that was called by **Apache**.

My first idea was simply to set an environment variable in the PHP script with `apache_setenv()` and use that variable in Apache conf with `CustomLog`.

Something like

PHP

```
apache_setenv('VAR=yes');
```

Apache

```
CustomLog "filename1" logFormat env=!VAR
CustomLog "filename2" logFormat env=VAR
```

Pretty straight forward, right?

Except that **it doesn't work**: `VAR` is never detected by Apache, log is always put in `filename1`

My next test was to print that variable **in the log line itself**, just to see if it was properly set.

Apache

```
LogFormat ... "%{VAR}e" ... logFormat
```

And it worked! I got `yes` in the appropriate *log line slot*.

So it seems the `apache_setenv` does create an environment variable, but **too late** for the `CustomLog` configuration.

I also tried:

1. `$_SERVER['VAR'] = 'yes';`
2. `$_ENV['VAR'] = 'yes';`

My only other idea left is to write the other log file *myself* with PHP, not through CustomLog. But that means I'll have to build the line log myself and "fake" the LogFormat.

Comment: You haven't stated your goal very clearly. You want to do what? And why?

Comment: I'm surprised that a post starting with "my goal is" doesn't state the goal clearly?? To say it different, my goal is to decide in a PHP script where Apache should log the hit: in a file if PHP variable is set to a specific value, in another file if this same PHP variable gets a different value. If my goal is still unclear, please state your question more clearly! ;-)